# Зависимый список увеличивается при каждом клике

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать зависимый список, но так, чтобы он постоянно проходил проверку того, что в нём выбрано. При этом он работает, но начинает постоянно увеличиваться при каждом клике. Как этого избежать?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col" id="calc">
        <select class="form-control" name="door_frame_type" id = "door_frame_type">
            <option>Без коробки</option>
            <option>Сосна</option>
        </select>
            <select class="form-control mt-2" name="door_frame_material" id = "door_frame_material">   
    </div> 
    
    <script>
        let calc = document.getElementById("calc")
        let door_frame_type = document.getElementById("door_frame_type");
        let type_frame = {birch_pine : ["Сосна", "50% сосна / 50% лиственница", "Лиственница", "50% сосна / 50% дуб", "Дуб",],}

        calc.addEventListener("change", function a() {
            if (door_frame_type.value == "Сосна") {
                door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[0]))
                door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[1]))
                door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[2]))
                door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[3]))
                door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[4]))
            }
        } 
        )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    door_frame_type.addEventListener("change", function() {
        door_frame_material.innerHTML = ''; // <--
        if (door_frame_type.value == "Сосна") {
            door_frame_material.add(new Option (type_frame.birch_pine[0]));
            ...
```